# com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: IO Error: Connection reset while upserting a record with PDF on an OracleDb

Tags: java, spring, websphere, mybatis

We have a Java back-end, powered by Spring 3.2.17, which is deployed inside a WebSphere Liberty Application Server which belongs to the customer, so I don't have access to it. 
We're trying to create a record in an Oracle DB in order to insert a PDF that we download from an external service. This information is returned to as a byte[].

This is the upsert query that we are using, via MyBatis-Spring

```
<update id="upsert">
MERGE INTO T_PDF PDF USING dual ON(PDF.CODICE_FISCALE = #{codiceFiscale} AND PDF.ID_PRATICA= #{idPratica})
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET
            DATA_UPDATE = SYSDATE
            <if test="nome != null and nome != ''" >
            , NOME = #{nome}
            </if>
            <if test="cognome != null and cognome != ''" >
            , COGNOME = #{cognome}
            </if>
            <if test="owner != null and owner != ''" >
            ,OWNER = #{owner}
            </if>
            <if test="isPrincipale != null and isPrincipale != ''" >
            ,IS_PRINCIPALE = #{isPrincipale}
            </if>
            <if test="isCensito != null and isCensito != ''" >
            , IS_CENSITO = #{isCensito}
            </if>
            <if test="stato!= null and stato != ''" >
            , STATO = #{stato}
            </if>
            <if test="unico != null and unico != ''" >
            , UNICO = #{unico}
            </if>
            <if test="consulenza!= null and consulenza != ''" >
            , CONSULENZA = #{consulenza}
            </if>
            <if test="mifid != null and mifid != ''" >
            , MIFID = #{mifid}
            </if>
            <if test="seiPdf != null and seiPdf != ''" >
            , SEI_PDF = #{seiPdf}
            </if>
            <if test="seiCommAtt != null and seiCommAtt != ''" >
            , SEI_COMM_ATT = #{seiCommAtt}
            </if>
            <if test="seiCommPer != null and seiCommPer != ''" >
            , SEI_COMM_PER = #{seiCommPer}
            </if>
            <if test="seiRicFatt!= null and seiRicFatt != ''" >
            , SEI_RIC_FATT = #{seiRicFatt}
            </if>
            <if test="apertura != null and apertura != ''" >
            , APERTURA = #{apertura}
            </if>
            <if test="miniQav != null and miniQav != ''" >
            , MINI_QAV = #{miniQav }
            </if>
            <if test="sintesi != null and sintesi != ''" >
            , SINTESI = #{sintesi}
            </if>
            <if test="informativo != null and informativo != ''" >
            , INFORMATIVO = #{informativo}
            </if>
            <if test="cambioIndirizzo != null and cambioIndirizzo != ''" >
            , CAMBIO_INDIRIZZO = #{cambioIndirizzo}
            </if>
            <if test="cambioInfo != null and cambioInfo != ''" >
            , CAMBIO_INFO= #{cambioInfo}
            </if>
            <if test="cambioIndirizzoEinfo != null and cambioIndirizzoEinfo != ''" >
            , CAMBIO_INDIRIZZO_E_INFO = #{cambioIndirizzoEinfo}
            </if>
            <if test="qavPb != null and qavPb != ''" >
            , QAV_PB = #{qavPb}
            </if>
            <if test="variazionePrivacy != null and variazionePrivacy != ''" >
            , VARIAZIONE_PRIVACY = #{variazionePrivacy}
            </if>
            <if test="trasferimentoQuote != null and trasferimentoQuote != ''" >
            , TRASFERIMENTO_QUOTE = #{trasferimentoQuote}
            </if>
            <if test="disposizioneMiniQav != null and disposizioneMiniQav != ''" >
            , DISPOSIZIONE_MINIQAV = #{disposizioneMiniQav}
            </if>
            <if test="omnibus != null and omnibus != ''" >
            , OMNIBUS = #{omnibus}
            </if>
            <if test="iniziativaWelcome != null and iniziativaWelcome != ''" >
            , INIZIATIVA_WELCOME = #{iniziativaWelcome}
            </if>
            <if test="firmaADistanza != null and firmaADistanza != '' ">
            , FIRMA_A_DISTANZA = #{firmaADistanza}
            </if>
            <if test="fatca != null and fatca != '' ">
            , FATCA = #{fatca}
            </if>
            <if test="qav != null and qav != '' ">
            , QAV = #{qav}
            </if>
            
           WHERE CODICE_FISCALE = #{codiceFiscale}
               AND ID_PRATICA = #{idPratica}
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT(
                OWNER,
                CODICE_FISCALE,
                NOME,
                COGNOME,
                IS_PRINCIPALE,
                IS_CENSITO,
                STATO,
                UNICO,
                CONSULENZA,
                MIFID,
                SEI_PDF,
                SEI_COMM_ATT,
                SEI_COMM_PER,
                SEI_RIC_FATT,
                APERTURA,
                MINI_QAV,
                SINTESI,
                INFORMATIVO,
                CAMBIO_INDIRIZZO,
                CAMBIO_INFO,
                CAMBIO_INDIRIZZO_E_INFO,
                QAV_PB,
                INIZIATIVA_WELCOME,
                ID_PRATICA,
                DATA_UPDATE,
                VARIAZIONE_PRIVACY,
                TRASFERIMENTO_QUOTE,
                DISPOSIZIONE_MINIQAV,
                OMNIBUS,
                STEP_IN,
                FIRMA_A_DISTANZA,
                FATCA,
                QAV
            ) 
            VALUES (
                #{owner},
                #{codiceFiscale},
                #{nome},
                #{cognome},
                #{isPrincipale},
                #{isCensito},
                #{stato},
                #{unico},
                #{consulenza},
                #{mifid},
                #{seiPdf},
                #{seiCommAtt},
                #{seiCommPer},
                #{seiRicFatt},
                #{apertura},
                #{miniQav},
                #{sintesi},
                #{informativo},
                #{cambioIndirizzo},
                #{cambioInfo},
                #{cambioIndirizzoEinfo},
                #{qavPb},
                #{iniziativaWelcome},
                #{idPratica},
                SYSDATE,
                #{variazionePrivacy},
                #{trasferimentoQuote},
                #{disposizioneMiniQav},
                #{omnibus},
                #{stepIn},
                #{firmaADistanza},
                #{fatca},
                #{qav}
            )
</update>
```

And  this is the snippet that we use for upserting

```
private void savePDF(TipoAdempimentoEnum tipoDocumento, byte[] adempimento,
                     String codiceFiscale, String rete,
                     Long idPratica, Long idTrasferimentoFondi, String matricolaPb) {
    Pdf pdf = new Pdf();
    pdf.setCodiceFiscale(codiceFiscale);
    pdf.setRetePB(rete);
    pdf.setOwner(matricolaPb);

    if(tipoDocumento.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("FTC")) {
        log.info("e' stato aggiunto il pdf del FTC");
        pdf.setFatca(adempimento);
    }
    if(tipoDocumento.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("QAV")) {
        log.info("e' stato aggiunto il pdf del QAV");
        pdf.setQav(adempimento);
    }
    if(idPratica != null) {
        log.info("e' stato trovato idPratica valorizzato");
        pdf.setIdPratica(""+idPratica);
        log.info("inizio salvataggio su T_PDF per il pdf di tipo {}", tipoDocumento);
        pdfMapper.upsert(pdf);
    }
    if(idTrasferimentoFondi != null) {
        log.info("e' stato trovato idTrasferimentoFondi valorizzato");
        pdf.setIdPratica(""+idTrasferimentoFondi);
        log.info("inizio salvataggio su T_PDF_TFSA per il pdf di tipo {}", tipoDocumento);
        pdfTFSAMapper.upsert(pdf);
    }

    log.info("fine salvataggio pdf sul database");
}
```

The operation, though, throws the following exception

```
INFO  05-03-2021 21:04:09,0420 [WebContainer : 1] some.package.db.mappers.PdfMapper [T88yjcid6CT2xptDPxYD8Jr][R011031] [WEB] - DAO : upsert - ARGS: [{"codiceFiscale":"BCHCZM45S52L892G","nome":null,"cognome":null,"isPrincipale":null,"isCensito":null,"owner":"R011031","stato":null,"idPratica":"23391","dataUpdate":null,"retePB":"F"}]
ERROR 05-03-2021 21:04:10,0935 [WebContainer : 1] some.package.db.mappers.PdfMapper [T88yjcid6CT2xptDPxYD8Jr][R011031] [WEB] -
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: IO Error: Connection reset
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: MERGE INTO T_PDF PDF USING dual ON(PDF.CODICE_FISCALE = ? AND PDF.ID_PRATICA= ?)  WHEN MATCHED THEN  UPDATE SET DATA_UPDATE = SYSDATE                       ,OWNER = ? , FATCA = ?  WHERE CODICE_FISCALE = ? AND ID_PRATICA = ? WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  INSERT( OWNER,CODICE_FISCALE, NOME,  COGNOME, IS_PRINCIPALE,               IS_CENSITO,  STATO,  UNICO, CONSULENZA,MIFID, SEI_PDF,SEI_COMM_ATT,               SEI_COMM_PER, SEI_RIC_FATT,  APERTURA, MINI_QAV,SINTESI,               INFORMATIVO,  CAMBIO_INDIRIZZO, CAMBIO_INFO,               CAMBIO_INDIRIZZO_E_INFO,   QAV_PB, INIZIATIVA_WELCOME,               ID_PRATICA,               DATA_UPDATE,  VARIAZIONE_PRIVACY,               TRASFERIMENTO_QUOTE,               DISPOSIZIONE_MINIQAV,               OMNIBUS,               STEP_IN,               FIRMA_A_DISTANZA,               FATCA,               QAV              )               VALUES (               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               SYSDATE,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?     )
### Cause: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: IO Error: Connection reset
; SQL []; IO Error: Connection reset; nested exception is com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: IO Error: Connection reset
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException:
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: IO Error: Connection reset
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: MERGE INTO T_PDF PDF USING dual ON(PDF.CODICE_FISCALE = ? AND PDF.ID_PRATICA= ?)              WHEN MATCHED THEN              UPDATE SET           DATA_UPDATE = SYSDATE                       ,OWNER = ?                                                                                                                                                                 , FATCA = ?                           WHERE CODICE_FISCALE = ?              AND ID_PRATICA = ?              WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN              INSERT(               OWNER,               CODICE_FISCALE,               NOME,               COGNOME,               IS_PRINCIPALE,               IS_CENSITO,               STATO,               UNICO,               CONSULENZA,               MIFID,               SEI_PDF,               SEI_COMM_ATT,               SEI_COMM_PER,               SEI_RIC_FATT,               APERTURA,               MINI_QAV,               SINTESI,               INFORMATIVO,               CAMBIO_INDIRIZZO,               CAMBIO_INFO,               CAMBIO_INDIRIZZO_E_INFO,               QAV_PB,               INIZIATIVA_WELCOME,               ID_PRATICA,               DATA_UPDATE,               VARIAZIONE_PRIVACY,               TRASFERIMENTO_QUOTE,               DISPOSIZIONE_MINIQAV,               OMNIBUS,               STEP_IN,               FIRMA_A_DISTANZA,               FATCA,               QAV              )               VALUES (               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               SYSDATE,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?,               ?     )
### Cause: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: IO Error: Connection reset
; SQL []; IO Error: Connection reset; nested exception is com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: IO Error: Connection reset
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:253)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
        at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:71)
        at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:365)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.update(Unknown Source)
        at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.update(SqlSessionTemplate.java:251)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:49)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:43)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.upsert(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at some.package.logger.AspectLogDaoMapper.logExecutionService(AspectLogDaoMapper.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor174.invoke(Unknown Source)
[...]

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at some.package.logger.AspectLogFilter.logExecutionService(AspectLogFilter.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor263.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:55)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy310.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at some.package.filter.CheckSessionFilter.doFilter(CheckSessionFilter.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor265.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at some.package.logger.AspectLogFilter.logExecutionService(AspectLogFilter.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor263.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:55)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy310.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at some.package.filter.ExpiredSessionFilter.doFilter(ExpiredSessionFilter.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor265.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at some.package.logger.AspectLogFilter.logExecutionService(AspectLogFilter.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor263.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:55)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy310.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4047)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: IO Error: Connection reset
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:58)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:542)
        at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapExceptionHelper(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:629)
        at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapException(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:688)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.mapException(AdapterUtil.java:2267)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcUtil.mapException(WSJdbcUtil.java:1219)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.execute(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:653)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:41)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:45)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:100)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:75)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:148)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:355)
        ... 179 more
```

This is the very first time that an upser that also inserts a byte array (marked as BLOB in the DB) actually causes this exception. I've searched SO a bit and saw that most of the suggestions are related to do something on the admin panel of WebSphere, but it's something to which I don't have access. Also, even if it throws Exception, the record is actually created in the database. 
What can I do to avoid this error? Is it, maybe, something related to the SQL query that is causing anyways this error?

EDIT: Full Stacktrace https://pastebin.com/UdzTum46

Comment: Could you replace the `[...]` with the actual trace? Does the exception occur even if there is no byte array parameter set?

Comment: @ave I’ll post it on a pastebin as SO cuts the post... and no, this doesn't occur if I don't set the byte[]

Comment: The `update()` call does not seem to reach the Oracle driver which implies a bug/limitation in WebSphare's driver wrapper or some kind of misconfiguration in WebSphere layer, but I cannot be certain. It might be worth executing the same statement with plain-old JDBC code i.e. `con = dataSource.getConnection(); stmt = con.prepareStatement("merge into ..."); stmt.execute();` to isolate the problem. MyBatis may use `PreparedStatement#setBytes` to set the byte array parameter unless you have custom type handler config.

Comment: @ave Fun fact: if I always use MyBatis, but simple INSERT and UPDATE statements, the query goes without any problem! What I can’t understand is that there are other points in the project that relies on this upsert for inserting PDFs in that table and works. And, no: I don’t have any peculiar handlers for the BLOB type

Comment: The same statement produces different results even with exactly the same parameters? If so, I'd suspect misconfiguration in transaction settings. Anyway, only you can find the key difference between working case and non-working case at this point. :)

Comment: @ave I agree, but your suggestion of using plain JDBC code made me first try the simple INSERT and UPDATE statement! :) Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The "StaleConnectionException" portion of the exception is coming from WebSphere, the "IO Error: Connection reset" is coming from the Oracle JDBC driver and typically points to the loss of the connection between Liberty and Oracle.  This can be due to a network timeout for a long running query or deadlock on some db resource like a table or row.  To troubleshoot further, you may find it helpful to use either the JDBC `timedOperations-1.0` feature of Liberty as described here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_timeop.html or the `eventLogging-1.0` feature as described here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_eventlogging.html

Comment: So if I tell my customer to enable either one of these features I should have more info in the logs?

Comment: Yes.  You could also turn on Oracle JDBC trace using the steps here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jdbc_trace.html

Comment: Thanks! i’ll see if my customer can do this (hopefully!), since I don’t have access to WebSphere :(